# CSS Spacing Under Two Widgets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the managers tab to be completely under the checkers and stockers areas on here and I can't get the manager button to cover under both of them.  Does anyone have anyway I need to address this issue?  The css is all in row but if there is another easy way to get about this I am all ears.  Thanks

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 1</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">14/15</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 4</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 7</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 2</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 5</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 8</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 3</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 6</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 text-right">
            <span>Phase 6</span>
            <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="widget navy-bg p-lg text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-columns fa-6x"></i>
        <h3 class="">Checkers</h3>
        <h2 class="font-bold no-margins">42/43</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-24">
        <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
              <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 text-right">
              <span>Managers</span>
              <h2 class="font-bold">9</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="widget navy-bg p-lg text-center">

        <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-6x"></i>
        <h3 class="">Stockers</h3>
        <h2 class="font-bold no-margins">12</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but for the last 8mins I'm trying to find stockers, I can't find that. please can you suggest me where is that

Comment: Sorry, its almost at the bottom of the code

Comment: what is `col-24`?

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want to have something like this. Just please don't devote me if I am not able to understand your concern.
Here is the code pen https://codepen.io/ash_000001/pen/dyZdQPa?editors=1010
with bootstrap4

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">

                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 1</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">14/15</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 4</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 7</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 2</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 5</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 8</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 3</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 6</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                        <span>Phase 6</span>
                                        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        
                            <div class="widget navy-bg p-lg text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-columns fa-6x"></i>
                                <h3 class="col-13 text-right">Checkers</h3>
                                <h2 class="font-bold no-margins col-13 text-right">42/43</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-24">
                                <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-8 text-right">
                                            <span>Managers</span>
                                            <h2 class="font-bold">9</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="widget navy-bg p-lg text-center">
```

Comment: You missed the last bit of code in the original question.

Comment: can you please explain that? I would love to help you

Comment: is that you want less css

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work well for you. I went through and cleaned up all the sizing on your elements, which is causing the result you have. In turn, this made your HTML much more minimal.

The main issue stems from nesting larger `col`'s in smaller `col'`s. For example: nesting a `col-8` and `col-4` in a `col-2` will cause issues.

```css
.col-2 {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="widget style1 navy-bg text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 1</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">14/15</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 2</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 3</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget style1 navy-bg text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 4</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 5</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 6</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget style1 navy-bg text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 7</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 8</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Phase 9</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">18/20</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget navy-bg p-md text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-columns fa-6x"></i>
        <h3 class="">Checkers</h3>
        <h2 class="font-bold no-margins">42/43</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
        <span>Managers</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold">9</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-6x"></i>
        <h3 class="">Stockers</h3>
        <h2 class="font-bold no-margins">12</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```